# Getting a value from Tkinter OptionMenu in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to print out the value selected in the option menu but only the first value gets printed everytime I run the code, even if I change my selection to b or c. Not sure where I'm wrong.This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.geometry("700x400")

options=StringVar(window)
options.set("a")
menu=OptionMenu(window,options, "a","b","c")
menu.grid(row=2,column=2)
selection=options.get()
print(selection)
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of tracing the variable, you can use the `command` option of the `OptionMenu`. Each time a menu item is clicked, the command is called. This command takes one argument: the item which is selected.

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(selection):
    print(selection)

root = tk.Tk()
options = tk.StringVar()
menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, options, 'a', 'b', 'c', command=callback)
menu.pack()
options.set('a')
root.mainloop()
```

In this case, the initially selected item is not printed because the user have not clicked on it. If you need `options.set('a')` to trigger your callback, then you will have to trace the variable like in mentalita's answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to invoke Tk's `mainloop` at the end of your code. Also, try tracing the `options` class variable.

From the [docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm): *You can use the trace method to attach “observer” callbacks to the variable. The callback is called whenever the contents change.*

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
options = tk.StringVar()
options.trace_add('write', lambda *args: print(options.get()))
menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, options, 'a', 'b', 'c')
menu.pack()
options.set('a')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay. Whats "w" stand for? I'm still new to python so getting trouble on a lot of stuff.

Comment: @West: it stands for 'write'. I've updated my answer to include a short explanation from the docs.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get the value selected and put it into a variable so I can use it anywhere?

Comment: I don't know which version of python you are using, but in python 3.6 `trace` is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html) and  `options.trace_add('write', lambda *args: print(options.get()))` should be used instead.

Comment: @j_4321: TIL. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning selection before the user has the chance to change the selected option.

Putting it in a function that calls when a 'save' button is pressed would likely be the simplest fix. You could also use a recursion loop to update it in real time but it's not a clean solution.

I'm assuming you've already included root.mainloop() in your actual script.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
import tkinter
window=tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("700x400")

option_Menu = tkinter.StringVar(window)
options = ("a","b","c")
menu = tkinter.OptionMenu(window,option_Menu,*options)
menu.grid(row=2,column=2)
option_Menu.set(2)
selection=option_Menu.get()

print(selection)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.